# Coffeescript - Replacing string

Tags: regex, coffeescript

I have a text and some strings coming from a JSON object:

```
links: [
  {text: "Bharath Karunamurthy", type: "User", id: 4},
  {text: "Raj Sanghvi", type: "User", id: 2}
]
text: "Bharath Karunamurthy follows Raj Sanghvi"
```

What I would like to do is to create a new text with links:

```
text_with_links: "<a href=/users/4 >Bharath Karunamurthy</a> follows <a href=/users/2 >Raj Sanghvi</a>"
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
text = this.text
for element in this.links
  text = text.replace /element.text/, "<a href='/users/"+element.id+"' >"+element.text+"</a>"
return text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the slashes.

```
text = text.replace element.text, "<a href='/users/"+element.id+"' >"+element.text+"</a>"
```

The string replace method works with strings as well as regex.

Comment: I need to keep the logic of replacing a string by another one, because I don't know its position in the sentence.

Comment: thanks ;) I didn't know about that, I thought you could only use Regex